# eric5(python IDE)：how to disappear the "Run Script" dialog

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyside

eric5(python IDE)：how to disappear the "Run Script" dialog

what bother me is that everytime I press F2 , the "Run Script" dialog always pops up ,but I hardly ever use it ，so how to disappear the "Run Script" dialog when the script is about to run ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't (currently but hopefully this will change).

There is a 'Restart Script (F4)' option that bypasses the 'Run Script' dialog and the 'program has terminated' dialog for runs after the first. It has a green arrow pointing in a circle on my version of Eric5 (5.3.3).

See here: [eric users group](http://www.mentby.com/Group/eric-users-list/preventing-run-script-dialog-from-popping-up.html)